Apache Atlas 2.3.0 Build Failure on Ubuntu (Java 11, Maven 3.6.3) - Zip END Header Not Found Error
I'm attempting to install Apache Atlas 2.3.0 on an Ubuntu server and encountering a build error related to the org.restlet dependency. Here are the details of my environment and the command I used to initiate the build:

Operating System: Ubuntu
Java Version: OpenJDK 11
Maven Version: 3.6.3
Python Version: 3.x

mvn -DskipTests -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true clean install
Error Output:
[INFO] Total time: 18.589
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-11-11T22:43:21+05:30
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project atlas-testtools: Compilation failures

[ERROR] error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet/2.4.3/org.restlet-2.4.3.jar; zip END header not found
[ERROR] error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.ext.servlet/2.4.3/org.restlet.ext.servlet-2.4.3.jar; zip END header not found
[ERROR] /root/apache-atlas-sources-2.3.0/test-tools/src/main/java/org/apache/atlas/runner/LocalSolrRunner.java: cannot access org.apache.atlas.runner
[ERROR] ZipException opening "org.restlet-2.4.3.jar": zip END header not found
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Were expecting...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  28:58 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-08T19:33:59Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------`

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Cleared Maven Repository: I removed the /root/.m2/repository/org/restlet/jee/ folder to force a redownload, but the issue persists.
Checked Network: Network access is available, and other dependencies download without issues.
Tried Debug Mode: Running Maven with the -e switch provided the same error without additional insights.
Has anyone encountered this specific "zip END header not found" error when building Apache Atlas or similar projects? Are there any additional steps I can take to resolve this, or is there an alternative way to obtain the missing JAR files?
